# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-templates.create) Could not fetch image resource:

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

The cluster was running fine for 255 days. I brought down the cluster and after that, I was unable to run the cluster up. It gives the following error while running the cluster up.

```
Creating minions.
Attempt 1 to create kubernetes-minion-template
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-templates.create) Could not fetch image resource:
 - The resource 'projects/google-containers/global/images/container-vm-v20170627' was not found

Attempt 1 failed to create instance template kubernetes-minion-template. Retrying.
```

This Attempt goes on and it always fails. Am I missing something?

The kubernetes version is v1.7.2.

Comment: Is this a GKE cluster?

Comment: @Rico Nope. Kubernetes is installed in Google VM instance.

Comment: What script are you using?  your own script or a publicly available script?

Comment: @Rico I was using my own script when I deployed 255 days ago. I tried with the same script it gave me above error and then I tried with **kube-up.sh** as well and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the image you are trying to use to create the machines has been deprecated and/or is no longer available.

You should try specifying an alternative image to create these machines from Google's current [public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support).